# Wiring ampmeter with reduced wire size

Tags: wire, awg

I have a solar system on a boat.
12v  8amp max
The wiring is 12 ga
The digital amp gauge I have has 20ga wire 2”long  ea total is 4”
This wire seems to small. Should I shorten the  gauge wires ??
Is it OK ?? Safe ??
Thanks. Nick

Comment: #20 wire seems a bit small for a meter intended to measure 10 Amps or more.  Is it possible that the meter is intended to be used with a shunt, rather than carrying the high current directly?

Answer (score 2):

#20 wire is simply too small to carry 10A.  UL won't approve that.

It also won't meet [boating codes](https://shop.pkys.com/wiring-standards.html).

So either this is a Chinese cheapie, or it is designed to use an ammeter shunt. (which on the negative side would be pretty safe).

An ammeter shunt is a really good idea.  Presumably you want that ammeter to be located somewhere useful, instead of between the panel and the charge controller.  You don't want the #12 power cable taking a long detour just to get the display where you want it - you want to keep the #12 cable runs as short as possible.  Voltage drop is a big deal when you're down at 12 volts.

With an ammeter shunt, you are free to put the ammeter where you want without worrying about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues: How much voltage will you lose at maximum current, and how hot will the wires get? The AWG wire tables show 4 inches of 20ga would be 3.7 milli-ohms of resistance. At 8A you would lose all of .03V. Not an issue. The power dissipated in the 4 inches of wire would be about 1/4 watt. Also not an issue. Hopefully no glaring arithmetic errors here! Neil.

Comment: 0.75 watts per foot on such small wire won't be able to cool safely.  No way did UL approve this.

Comment: Athough technically able to, 0.5mm will be nice and warm to the touch at 8A. Something around 50c or similar, in free air. Inside a conduit or pipe this wire will fail.